# Need help filtering an autocomplete array with react v17

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Most tutorials I found on this subject were outdated. So here I am.
What I expect to do with this app is, input text into the field and filter the results based on what you input. Currently I'm stuck and I've been through so many array methods such as filter, indexOf etc. I'm sure I am overthinking the issue so I need help. Here's the code I have currently:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ITEMS_API_URL = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";

function Autocomplete() {
  const [countryArr, setCountryArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(ITEMS_API_URL).then((res) => {
      setCountryArr(() => {
        let arr = res.data;
        arr.splice(10, arr.length);
        return arr;
      });
      console.log(countryArr);
    });
  }, []);


  const onChange = e => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value
    const filteredSuggestions = countryArr.find(arr => arr.name == inputValue)
    setCountryArr(filteredSuggestions)

    
  }
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="control">
        <input type="text" className="input" onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="list is-hoverable" />
        {countryArr.map((country) => {
          return (
            <ul key={country.numericCode}>
              {country.name}
            </ul>

          )
        })}
    </div>
  );
}


export default Autocomplete;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not change to actual data source (`countryArr`) otherwise it reset and store last filtered on that. so I create state variable `filteredCountryArr` for filter and setting up filtered valued on that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ITEMS_API_URL = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";

function Autocomplete() {
  const [countryArr, setCountryArr] = useState([]);
  const [filteredCountryArr, setFilteredCountryArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(ITEMS_API_URL).then(res => {
      setCountryArr(() => {
        let arr = res.data;
        arr.splice(10, arr.length);
        return arr;
      });
      console.log(countryArr);
    });
  }, []);

  const onChange = e => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    const filteredSuggestions = countryArr.find(arr => arr.name == inputValue);
    setFilteredCountryArr(filteredSuggestions);
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="control">
        <input type="text" className="input" onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="list is-hoverable" />
      {filteredCountryArr && filteredCountryArr.length > 0  && filteredCountryArr.map(country => {
        return <ul key={country.numericCode}>{country.name}</ul>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

Comment: That gave me an error property of map undefined
https://i.ibb.co/PGP4Y8n/Screenshot-376.png

Comment: filteredCountryArr && filteredCountryArr.length > 0 && filteredCountryArr.map add condition